# Back (arrow) button opens a read-only copy of the same file

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-visio

Here are the steps that I take to replicate this problem:

> I open an Office application file (e.g., a Word document) from a DFS Shared location on our network.
> I click on a cross-reference therein to another location in the same file.
> I click on the back button to return to the original location in such file but this opens the same file in Read-only mode, the file path is the UNC path of the server (e.g., \FileServerName\Filepath) instead of DFS share (e.g., \DFSShare\Filepath).
>
> > This used to work for us, essentially since the beginning of time.
> > But, recently, I starting observing that the back button opens up a read-only copy of the same file, and jumps back to the original location in the read-only file.

I have noticed this behaviour happening in our Office 365 application implementation, starting a couple of months ago.

I have so far confirmed that this behaviour happens in Excel, Visio, and Word. I installed a new, clean computer, and the problem also is happening there.
Interestingly, if I copy the file to a local client computer folder, the problem does not happen.

This behaviour is very disabling because I can no longer go back to the source location after clicking on a hyperlink.

Any ideas at debugging this are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I experience the exact same misbehavior in the Office 365 EXCEL application.
It makes smooth hyperlink travelling inside my EXCEL documents impossible.
Removal of the Back-button from my menu (so that I don't push it accidentally) seems to be the only 'fix' for now.
But I would really appreciate a real solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).